# Can @page rule be used inside @media print?

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet, printing-web-page

I have something like the following in my CSS, in order to be friendly to the `edit styles` bookmarklet, which doesn't support the `media` attribute of the `style` tag, so, I explicitly use `@media print` for the whole style.

```
@media print {

  @page {
margin: 1cm;
margin-top: 12mm;
size: portrait;
  }
  body {
font: 9.3pt "Hoefler Text", "Franklin Gothic Book", sans-serif;
max-width: 80em;
border: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
  }
  /* more stuff here */
}
```

However, it would seem like http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input doesn't like this, producing the following errors:

```
7       Parse Error @page { margin: 1cm; margin-top: 12mm; size: portrait; }
16      Parse Error /* more stuff here */ }
```

However, if I move [the `@page` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page) to outside of `@media print`, then no errors are reported.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the validator?

[According to MDN, browser support is pretty new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542320/margin-while-printing-html-page) [confirms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page/2780518#2780518), even though this has been [part of the original CSS2 recommendation from 1998](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html), pretty much unchanged.

Comment: Interesting, even code under [`8.1.2. Media Queries`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size-media-query) doesn't get validated

Answer (score 1):

Quote from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166):

> Now, the actual issue here is that nested `@media` rules are [not valid in CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule) because you're not allowed to nest *any* at-rules within `@media` rules.

However, according to the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing) is possible, as the previous answer states. I think you can move safely this rule outside the `@media print` rule, since by itself is for *printing* the document. Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page):

> The `@page` CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when printing a document.

Comment: Yes, it could be moved out, but then it kinda looks ugly and out-of-line, since then not all parts of a given `<style media="print"` tag are within `@media print`.  But thanks for finding it out that it's explicitly invalid in CSS21!