# Leaving margin at bottom of print (JSP, CSS)

Tags: css, jsp, printing, margin

Could anyone please tell how shall I leave a margin at the bottom of the page even when the table is extending over a page (Please see the image). While printing I am missing the one or two rows at the bottom.

I have tried using @page{ body {margin-bottom:2cm;}} but it does not seem to work for me.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542320/margin-while-printing-html-page