# Aligment issue in window.print using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I am using java-script window.print for my print div. When I print that div than I alignment issue in my print page.

Below my code which is I have used for print and also I have upload both image. First is my output image and second is which I was print that layout.

```
  function PrintPopup() {
        var data = $("#viewCoupon").html();
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print Data', 'height=540,width=980');
        mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Bonus Box Offer</title>");
        mywindow.document.write("<link href=\"Content/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
        mywindow.document.write("<style>.userwinners{margin-top: 51px;margin-left: 0;} .no-Print{display:none;}  @media print {.no-Print{display:none;} title {display:none;} }</style>");
        mywindow.document.write("</head><body >");
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        //mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please put your html code here.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542320/margin-while-printing-html-page) and format your page with appropriate margins.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle .. for better understanding .. the issue needs to be fixed in you `html` and `css`

Answer (score 0):

Use separate CSS file. So, you can align the page using CSS in a better way as you are expecting. Here is the code for CSS file include and this only effect for PRINT.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

So you can add whatever CSS you want to align your print page.