# CSS print a custom sized page margin when the content is on multiple pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to print an HTML page that might be long and contain text paragraphs and tables. My goal is to define a print margin **for every page**. 
I added the following CSS to my page:

```
@media print {
    body {
        margin: 2.5cm 0;
    }
}
```

But the problem that I have is that the margin gets added **only** to the beginning and end of the document and NOT to every single page.
As you can see from the attached image I have a margin top in the first page but not in the second one, my desired behavior is something similar to a book or a word document (where you define page margins).
Is it possible to do it in CSS?

[issue visibile in the print preview screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3chej.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
@media print {
   body {
   display:table;
   table-layout:fixed;
   padding-top:2.5cm;
   padding-bottom:2.5cm;
   height:auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Satya, but I have the same problem (no margin in the second page).

Comment: Then try this..it should work:   @page { margin: 2.5cm 0 }

Comment: FYI: Neither solution works in Webkit / Safari (as of v11, in 2017): @page is not supported, and setting the body's margin or padding only works for the first page, unfortunately. Other browsers support `@page`, which is ultimately the best solution, it seems.

Answer (score 15):

## CSS for Printed Page Margins

```css
@page {
  margin: 1in; // margin for each printed piece of paper
}

@page :first {
  margin-top: 2in; // top margin for first page of paper
}

@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0; // 
  }
}
```

---

## Print Dialog Settings

In the print preview dialog, ensure that "Margins" is set to "Default".

If "Margins" are set to "None" (or other non-"Default" option) the `@page` settings will be ignored.

## Browser Support

[@page is not supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media). Learn more about [@page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page).

Comment: It does work for multiple pages! That's the whole point of `@page` 

Comment: This creates the correct margin on each page.  If we use this approach is there a way to remove the browser header and footer?  i.e. the URL and page title?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I needed. My homemade table from the divs was cut off from the top on page 2. I set the top margin for the first page to 0, and for the rest - 3em. Everything worked!