# CSS - left hand image run full height of print

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to design a HTML document that can be printed in A4 and needs to be printed from IE.

As part of the requirement I need to have a ribbon running down the left handside of the page and this needs to be the full height of the printed page.   I have manage to satisfy all requirements apart from this ribbon which I cannot get to run the whole length of the page (please see example[1](http://s1064.photobucket.com/user/kev_wired1/media/Capture_zpssnlxgpe2.png.html)).

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to change the margins on the page, so the image can position right to the edge. Have a look at this answer: [Margin while printing html page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1542543/2142071)

Although, keep in mind that all printers will need (and/or use) some margin. So you might want to look at that in your design.