# Margins for body on each page (print)

Tags: html, css, less, printing-web-page

Is there a solution for setting the `margin-top`, `margin-bottom` in print view for each view of a printed page?

I have tried with `@page` or by setting the margin in `body {}` but it does not seem to be working. (it sets `margin-top` just for the first page)

Comment: Did you try providing "!important" near the margins to overwrite any other possible style?

Comment: You need to put your code so we can help.

Comment: works fine for me in chrome and firefox. Could you pls give a snippet or fiddle

Comment: I am not sure we can do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
body {
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;
}
```

take a look here for detailed answer: [Margin while printing html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542320/margin-while-printing-html-page)

Comment: Only applied first page. that's not what was asked.

Comment: This does not create the correct margin on page 2